# Passing variable to next page through url

Tags: php

Here I am counting the number of persons a profile owner is following, and the output number is link to open a new page were all persons being followed will be displayed, the count works well and gives the number of persons being followed but now to complete my next page say `following.php` where all persons being followed will be displayed I need to pass variable `$id` to that page for which I want to use url method, please help me on this.

```
<?php
$checkfollowing =$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM follow_user WHERE uid_fk=:id");
$checkfollowing->execute(array(':id'=>$id)); 
$count = $checkfollowing->rowCount(); ?>
<a href='following.php' style='text-decoration:none;margin-left:40px;'><?php print $count; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass value by url and get the value on other page by using `$_GET` method.
check the below code.

```
<a href='following.php?id=<?php echo $id ; ?>' style='text-decoration:none;margin-left:40px;'><?php print $count; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href='following.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>' style='text-decoration:none;margin-left:40px;'><?php print $count; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a variable through url by specifieng your variable at end of your url. like this

```
<a href='following.php?count=<?php echo $count; ?>' style='text-decoration:none;margin-left:40px;'><?php print $count; ?></a>
```